# Is this gray fibrous substance above my ceiling tile made of asbestos?

Tags: ceiling, asbestos

This is above my ceiling tile.  Is it asbestos?

[image: asbestos?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It could be.**

A few things you've left out where the year of the build of your home and the area you are in. These could help narrow down if this was used in your area at the time of construction.

You have two options:

1. Pickup a test kit from your local hardware store - or bring a sample to be tested by a lab.
2. Call a qualified professional for an opinion: Knowledgeable contractors can identify this immediately or you can contact the local authority in your area who deals with asbestos.

Since there is a doubt, stop everything you are doing until you've confirmed what it is.

Comment: If you do not disturb it and cover it back up in place you will be fine. As long as you don't cause it to become airborne there is no health hazard, whether it is asbestos or not.

Comment: Agreed, I had that written in originally, but it's tough to know if when the OP opened it up if dust got kicked up.

Comment: Hopefully not, yet some exposure is not a huge concern. Even a simple dust mask provides some protection. The 8hr. allowable exposure is 0.1 fibers per cubic centimeter, 30 minute allowable up to 1.0 fibers per cubic centimeter. No way to home measure but as long as OP is careful handling it moving forward, likely no harm done. The biggest concern is for those with repeated occupational exposure.

Comment: Seems it was asbestos. Called the building manager and promptly got kicked out for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and confirming. +1 all too often people ask a question and we never hear anything again.